# How to connect Wordpress and Firebase for authentication and real time database?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on a combined Android and WordPress project for a restaurant. I need to connect WordPress to an existing real-time Firebase database and authentication. My Android is working with Firebase and supports sending and retrieving data but I am unable to apply this with WordPress. So far the database does not update properly and no changes are shown on the app. I am using WordPress for the admin to make change prices, add new food, and generate reports. The Android component is customer facing and intended to allow ordering food.

I have tried using a normal static website and it was connected to Firebase but I am unsure how to implement this with WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin - Integrate Firebase that connects Firebase to Wordpress.

I have been able to get it working, but it seems to work on the API key rather than using a service account. Which means you need to have the rules set in firebase.

The author seems reasonably active, so I am hoping to get more info about connecting with a service account (rather than API), in which case I'll post it here for you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across another plugin WP Firebase Authentication that provides an addon for this functionality and the setup seems quite simple. I did not need to set or change any rules in Firebase with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).